# Плавная анимация

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый вечер! Возник вопрос, как сделать плавный скроллинг. Т.е. при прокрутке колесика страница автоматически прокручивается до определенного положения?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте css-трансформации (в вашем случае `translateY`) для задания смещения при прокрутке. Далее используете css-transitions для задания скорости перемещения (например, `transition: all 0.3s;`). Лучше это реализовывать на чистом JS, чем через JQuery и прочие фреймворки (будет большая плавность анимации и более быстрый отклик при появлении события прокрутки).